# Docker image name

Tags: docker-image

How to create a image/tag name for the existing image? I have following images currently:

[image]

I would like to create repository name and tag name of the existing image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use docker tag for this

`docker tag cdcbb3706c83 {your tag name}`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Answer (score 0):

I have used following command to create repository and tag name:

`docker tag cdcbb3706c83 aspcore:dev`

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [docker tag manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) you can use

```
docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]
```

example

```
 docker tag 0e5574283393 fedora/httpd:version1.0
```